# Updating model attributes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to enable a user to change the status of incoming friend requests from "unaccepted" to "accepted"

## User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
has_many :places


has_many :sent_friendships, class_name: "Friendship" , foreign_key: :sender_id
has_many :received_friendships, class_name: "Friendship", foreign_key: :receiver_id
```

## Friendship Model

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User"
end
```

## User Show View

```
    <h1>Incoming Friend Requests</h1>
<% current_user.received_friendships.each do |friendship| %>
<%= friendship.sender.name %>
<%= link_to "Accept", user_accept_path(current_user), class: 'btn btn-success', method: :post %>
<% end %>
```

## Friendships Controller

```
 class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController

def accept
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])



end

end
```

Where is where I am stumbling because I am unsure as to how best to plus in the sender id and receiver id to update the proper line on the Friendship model table.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As every your controller has access to `current_user` variable, you may not pass it as parameter, but you should pass a `friendship.sender` to it.

Then depending on you routes and architecture you may do one of the following:

1. Create a new Frienship

   class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController

   ```
   def accept
       @user = User.find(params[:id])
       friendship.create sender_id: current_user.id, reciever_id: @user.id
       # or
       # friendship.create sender_id: current_user.id, reciever_id: params[:id]

       # then rdictect to somewhere
       redirect ...
   end
   ```

   end
2. If you have additional fields in the Frienship model like - accepted, you may update. Then you find a created Frienship model during send of friendship
   invitation and update the field.

   class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController

   ```
   def accept
       @user = User.find(params[:id])
       friendship = Frienship.where("sender_id = ? and reciever_id = ?",
                                # sender was passed as an argument to link_to in the view
                                   @user.id, current_user.id)
       friendship.accept = true
       friendship.save!


       # then rdictect to somewhere
       redirect ...
   end
   ```

   end

Answer (score 1):

Your `accept` method should basically do a set of things:

1. Obtain a user who accepts the request (you should already have this done for you as `devise` has `current_user` helper method accessible in controller)
2. Obtain a corresponding `received_friendship` to know which particular user is going to be a new friend for `current_user`
3. Update the `friendship` object (from step #2) to have `acceptance` (or whatever you named it) attribute set to `accepted`.

As you already know, first step does not require any coding from you. The second one should be as simple as setting a local (or @instance) variable based on `sender_id` of friendship request (or `id` of particular `friendship`, which would be even better). And the last one would look something like

```
friendship.acceptance = "accepted"
if friendship.save
  # TODO: redirect to somewhere with a successful notice
else
  # TODO: render users/show template once again with an error
end
```

One more hint: note that your acceptance link does not pass data required at step #2:

```
<%= link_to "Accept", user_accept_path(current_user) %>
```

Comment: I had a feeling my link was incorrect.  Would user_accept_path(friendship.sender.id) be what I need?

Comment: yes. It would provide data about the person you want to accept. `current_user` is available everywhere.

Comment: based on your decision this can be either `friendship.sender_id` or `friendship.id` itself. my choice would be the latter option.